# Core's ClassResolver cannot find my custom module class, gives InvalidArgumentException

Tags: forms, 8

TL;DR:  see error message at the bottom.

Yes, this is the very basic question on "How do I make a simple custom form" using Drupal 8.1.  I have read through 3 different sites and still having trouble.

My steps are to create these files:

**Routing**

```
./sites/all/modules/testmodule/testmodule.routing.yml
```

```
testmodule.fruit_form:
  path: '/testmodule/ask-user'
  defaults:
    _title: 'Fruit Form'
    _form: '\Drupal\testmodule\Form\FruitForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

**Info**

```
./sites/all/modules/testmodule/testmodule.info.yml
```

```
name: Test Module
type: module
description: Sample module that defines a route and form callback.
core: 8.x
```

**Form File**

```
./sites/all/modules/testmodule/src/Form/FruitForm.php
```

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\testmodule\Form;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
class FruitForm extends FormBase {
  protected $accepted_domains = ['gmail.com', 'yahoo.com'];
  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'fruitform';
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $fruits = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Blueberry', 'Grapes', 'Orange', 'Strawberry'];
    $form['favorite_fruit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'select',
      '#title' => $this->t('Tell us your favorite fruit.'),
      '#required' => true,
      '#options' => array_combine($fruits, $fruits)
    );
    $form['email_address'] = array(
      '#type' => 'email',
      '#title' => $this->t('What is your email address?'),
      '#required' => true,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit!'),
    );
    return $form;
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    if (!filter_var($form_state->getValue('email_address'), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
      $form_state->setError($form['email_address'], 'Email address is invalid.');
    }
    if (!$this->validEmailAddress($form_state->getValue('email_address'))) {
      $form_state->setError($form['email_address'], 'Sorry, we only accept Gmail or Yahoo email addresses at this time.');
    }
  }
  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    drupal_set_message($this->t('@fruit! Wow! Nice choice! Thanks for telling us!', array('@fruit' => $form_state->getValue('favorite_fruit'))));
    $form_state->setRedirect('<front>');
  }
  /**
   * Check the supplied email address that it matches what we will accept.
   * @param $email_address
   * @return bool
   */
  protected function validEmailAddress($email_address) {
    $domain = explode('@', $email_address)[1];
    return in_array($domain, $this->accepted_domains);
  }
}
```

Contents of the above files are [here](https://github.com/kevinquillen/testmodule)

For tutorial I used search the web for "technical-guide-drupal-8-forms"

I then go to http://domain/testmodule/ask-user

and nothing.  It says Page Not Found

How do I make it found?

**Enabling the Module**

After enabling the module I got

```
Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: 
"Class "\Drupal\testmodule\Form\FruitForm" does not exist." 
at core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ClassResolver.php line 24
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the relevant code from your module's files.

Comment: Added code from the files.  I assume that's what you were requesting?

Comment: Did you enable the module? Or rebuild cache after uploading an existing module?

Comment: Tested the module, works fine here. So yeah, my guess is also "is the module enabled?"

Comment: I am guessing the module is not enabled.  How do I enable it?   I tried clearing the cache but that did nothing as far as enabling routing.

Comment: You go to the "Extend" page (admin/modules), look for your module and install it.

Comment: Thanks.  I am getting somewhere.  I now get "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later."   Going to look into that ...

Comment: I get Uncaught PHP Exception InvalidArgumentException: "Class "\Drupal\testmodule\Form\FruitForm" does not exist." at core/lib/Drupal/Core/DependencyInjection/ClassResolver.php line 24

Comment: Thanks.  The "Enable Module" suggestion was most helpful.  I don't know why I got another error after enabling the module.

Comment: uninstalled Drupal, going with ZF2 at the moment